# Python subprocess in linux on cloudshare

Tags: python, linux, kubectl, popen

I am trying to write a mini-program to allow user to start or stop all process indicate after:

```
kubectl exec -it deploy/tss -c tss bash
```

is executed

This should change user to root but when i continue, i have the execution for last user not root

My code:

```
kubectl = 'kubectl exec -it deploy/tss -c tss bash'
commandkub = shlex.split(kubectl)
pk = subprocess.Popen(commandkub)
pk.wait
pk.terminate  
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) <-- this uses the last user instead of root
```

The testing code is here (change command to ls)

```
[tufin-admin@TufinOS ~]$ ls
demo.yaml  sample  test.py
[tufin-admin@TufinOS ~]$ kubectl exec -it deploy/tss -c tss bash
[root@tss-6964cf6565-96wks /]# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  
sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
[root@tss-6964cf6565-96wks /]# exit
[tufin-admin@TufinOS ~]$ python test.py start
[root@tss-6964cf6565-96wks /]# ['demo.yaml\n', 'sample\n', 'test.py\n']
```

My python version is 2.7.5.

Any advise?

Comment: what is `command` (it's not defined in the code snippet you show)?

Comment: command = ['st', 'stat']